# remove parentheses from JSON string

Tags: ios, json, nsstring

After extracting a string from JSON response:

```
 NSString *responseMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[JSON objectForKey:@"Response"]valueForKey:@"Message"]];
 NSLog(@"<%@>",responseMessage);
```

It looks like this:

```
<(
    "not found"
)>
```

This is the relevant code:

So when I try to compare it, `isEqualToString` returns always `false`

```
([responseMessage isEqualToString:@"not found"])?NSLog(@"They are equal"):NSLog(@"They are different");//they are different
```

How to get rid of these parentheses to better compare the two strings? Thanx in advance.

Comment: I know, I mean that's the NSLog after extracting it from JSON. Don't stop at details :)

Comment: Where does the parenthesis come from if it's JSON? Unless they are part of the string, they should come from an array. If that's the case you can just access the array to get the string you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an array here (which in Objective-C will print as a list with parentheses).

What is the source JSON string?

If it is an array, you want to iterate over its elements, or maybe just pull out the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to remove **if** any brackets existing in your code. You can find different combinations for regular expressions to use.

```
     NSString *expression = @"\\s+\\([^()]*\\)";
     while ([responseMessage rangeOfString:expression options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location!=NSNotFound)
     {
          responseMessage = [responseMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:expression withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [responseMessage length])];
     }

     NSLog(@"returnResponse %@",responseMessage);
```